# How to let std::vector allocate memory from a specified memory space?

Tags: c++

I have two processes that share memory through `boost::interprocess::windows_shared_memory`.

I want a `std::vector` to use this memory, so that I can simply access the container data in another memory instead of passing it around in a C style.

Suppose I have a pointer to memory and memory size:

```
PVOID buffer = xxx;
size_t size = xxx;
```

How to change `std::allocator` to realize this function?

Comment: Have you tried reading the reference for `std::allocator`? It tells you how to implement the required functionality. Is there something in `std::allocator`'s specifications that are unclear to you?

Comment: Indeed, [allocating from `boost::interprocess` shared memory](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator#Fancy_pointers) is explicitly called out as a use case.